# Exact same JavaScript codes not works on local computer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tested on JSFiddle without problem

This is the file hosted on a server: http://users3.jabry.com/apasajja/37/file.html

It works perfectly. The image loaded every second.

But when run on local computer, it not works as expected, even the codes are same. The image is not loaded every second.

You can have the same copy: http://users3.jabry.com/apasajja/37/file.zip

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Why didn't you added your code here? __Add relevant code here__

Comment: local mean from localhost or directly opened it in browser?????

Comment: If you're double clicking the HTML file and it contains `<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>`, the jQuery code won't be loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

**Change from this**

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
```

**to**

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention  DOCTYPE and html 
try this one it works.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">


    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.js">   </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mr3{
        height:200px
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mr3" style="background:url(http://users3.jabry.com/apasajja /37/banner1.jpg)">  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```